# Swift 4.Decodable + alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, decodable

I have a trouble with decoding `JSON`.Trying to get sunrise and sunset time, but nothing is working.
Help

```
func getData(latitude: String,longtitude: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=\(latitude)&lng=\(longtitude)")
    Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
        do {
            let st = try JSONDecoder().decode(results.self, from: data)
            print(st.sunrise)
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a root struct to decode too like this

```
struct Root : Decodable {
   let status: String
   let results: results
}

struct results: Decodable {
    let sunrise : string 
    //other struc proporties as well in here 
let astronomical_twilight_end: String
}
```

so 
you can do this

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

let result = root.result